# How do you clear old references in Xcode 4.X

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created a project in Xcode, added a splash screen then deleted it. Now when I create a new project with the same name - the splash screen is automatically used.

My guess is this is due to a reference from a previous project? How do I clear this stuff out for good?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your project.

Go to Product -> Clean.

Comment: Just found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4

I did what matt said "Even better, quit Xcode and clean out Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually. Remove all its contents because there's a bug where Xcode will run an old version of your project that's in there somewhere."